# How to specify multiple Spark Standalone masters (for spark.master property)?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have 1 master with 3 worker nodes communicating to master.

As a disaster recovery we have created 2 Masters and let zookeeper elect the master. I am using datastax's spark Cassandra connector. Is there a way to pass multiple Spark Master URLs to try serially which ever succeeds.

```
new SparkConf(true)
        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "10.3.2.1")  
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.username","cassandra")
        .set("spark.cassandra.auth.password",cassandra"))
        .set("spark.master", "spark://1.1.2.2:7077") // Can I give multiple Urls here?
        .set("spark.app.name","Sample App");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use comma to separate `host:port` entries, e.g. `spark://localhost:7077,localhost:17077`

Please note that you should avoid hardcoding connection details as they are part of operations and should really be defined using spark-submit's `--master` command-line option:

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --help

Options:
  --master MASTER_URL         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port, yarn, or local.
```

---

See the [relevant Spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.scala#L2733) where the parsing happens:

```
val masterUrls = sparkUrl.split(",").map("spark://" + _)
```

while `sparkUrl` is matched using `"""spark://(.*)""".r` regex.